# SPFx webpart onPropertyChanged didn't fire after control's content was changed

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I am recently trying the SPFx webpart for Drop 5. I understood that the drop 5 started to use @microsoft/sp-webpart-base instead of @microsoft/sp-client-preview. What I did was to add two dropdown controls and dropdownB's list was depended on dropdownA. As I understand correctly, the ***protected onPropertyChanged(propertyPath: string, oldValue: any, newValue: any): void*** method should be triggered whenever dropdownA is changed at reactive mode. However, this method didn't triggered when I connected to SPO. This method can be fired at local mode. Anyone has ideas about this? I kindly remembered it was fine on both local and SPO under Drop 4.

```
    protected onPropertyChanged(propertyPath: string, oldValue: any, newValue: any): void {
      console.log("onPropertyChanged: " + propertyPath);
      super.onPropertyChanged(propertyPath, oldValue, newValue);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

1. upgrade to drop 6 (https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Release-Notes-Drop-6)
2. method signature has changed to `"onPropertyPaneFieldChanged(...)"` with the same parameters and return type as before.

Comment: Glad to see Drop 6 came out. I followed the Drop 6 instruction and I got the following error when WebPack built the package. `[12:00:55] Error - [webpack] 'dist':
./~/@microsoft/sp-module-loader/lib/SystemJsWrapper.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'raw-script' in`

Comment: If you create a webpart from scratch do you get the same error?  Are you including any extra libraries in your code?

Comment: got a chance to deep dive this issue. This error happened when I created a brand-new project based on drop 6 and referenced a external css using `ModuleLoader.loadCss('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');`. This issue was gone after I added `"@microsoft/loader-raw-script": "0.0.5"` in my package.json. However, I got another error `[15:21:06] Error - [webpack] 'dist':
./~/@microsoft/sp-module-loader/lib/SPModuleLoader.resx.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'resx-strings' in ` . It looks like Webpack missed this loader.

Comment: Does this thread solve your issue - https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/286